# How can I target the website <head> instead of the popup.html <head> when appending a stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Per the question asked, is it possible for me to target the  element of a specific website instead of my popup.html using JavaScript? The link in the manifest has been removed from this question.

My JS file

```
function myAlert(){
    alert('You have activated dark mode!');
         // Create new link Element
         var link = document.createElement('link');
         link.rel = 'stylesheet';
         link.type = 'text/css';
         link.href = 'css/dark-mode.css';
         document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(link);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('darkMode').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
});
```

My manifest file

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Dark Mode Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.WEBSITEHERE.com/*"],
    "js": ["js/dark-mode.js"]
  }
],

"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "storage", "notifications"]
```

}

The stylesheet is added to the popup.html and not the website when the button is pressed
[image: Picture of result]

Comment: You can inject css in your content script.

Comment: Yes, and another solution is to use chrome.scripting.insertCSS and chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts, which is more performant.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Yeah, I did have that before I tried using JS. But I want to build an extension where you can switch between different dark mode styles. If I put the CSS file in content script, it toggles the CSS instantly